# I am trying to make a JS function for full screen in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I have have gone through many resources related to view full screen but none of the JS related functions are working in LWC.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="xyz">
  <div class="jkl">
       <template if:true={full}>
          <div class="abc">
            <lightning-icon size="small" icon-name="utility:expand_alt" alternative-text="Full Screen" onclick={fullScreen}></lightning-icon>
          </div>
       </template>
  </div>
</div>
```

//JS:

```
fullScreen(){
    var elem = document.documentElement;
    if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
        elem.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    }else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { 
        elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
        elem.msRequestFullscreen();
    }
}
```

What else do I need in LWC to make it work for view full scree and exit it.

Comment: Seems like document.documentElement won't work due to locker service. which element are you trying to show on fullscreen?

Comment: I think I should use this.template.querySelector() to query instead event.target . Now what I am trying to do is to access the lightning-icon so that when a user clicks on that then it will fire the fullScreen function

Comment: yes, you can use the query selector.

Comment: thanks! for the response @RahulGawale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Only Work in LWC OSS and not supported by Lightning Locker as of now.

You need to call the full-screen API function on an element. You can do it like this.

```
  fullScreen(event){
    // add the selector for your desired component that you want to show fullscreen below.
    var elem = this.template.querySelector("selector-for-component"); 
    if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
        elem.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    }else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { 
        elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
        elem.msRequestFullscreen();
    }
  }
```

Please note that it show the content from the target element only. You might need to query the desired element and call these method on that.

Comment: It's still doesn't work

Comment: See [here](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/phsktsgYoMEV8TJKhsp5/src/app.html)

Comment: @HJohn You might need to query the outermost element and call this method on that instead of the `event.target`.

Comment: Yes, it is working here, let me check at my end, what I am missing

Comment: I just copy paste your code, but it's still doesn't work at my end

Comment: I have updated my code, if you can look into it

Comment: it is not working for me also. Any idea on how it was implemented

Comment: @anmrk you need to call this method from the element that you want to show full-screen then all its Contents are shown full-screen.

Comment: this doesn't work in lightning container due to locker

Comment: yeah looks like this is not supported from recent updates. @anmrk.